# Why is MySQL INSERT statement not working without error

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

A php/mySQL booking function that's been working well suddenly stopped inserting booking entries into the database, with no changes to the code and a functioning database connection.

I run a parallel version of the page that *is* working on another website; the only difference between the two is that the broken version is running on php 5.6, the functioning one is still on 5.4.

Adding an error log brings no results even though the table doesn't update and I can't see any deprecated statements between php 5.4 and 5.6.

Can anyone spot the problem I'm missing?

```
 //If the confirm button has been hit:
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Create the foreach loop
  foreach ($_POST['class_id'] as $classes) {
  $class_id = (int)$classes;
  //UPDATE the bookings table **THIS PART IS NOT WORKING**:
  $query = "INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, booking_name, class_id, time_stamp) VALUES ('$user_id', '$username', '$class_id', NOW())";
  mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

}
foreach($_POST['class_id'] as $classes){
  $class_id = (int)$classes;
  //Change the booking numbers **THIS WORKS FINE**:
  $increase = "UPDATE classes SET online_bookings = (online_bookings + 1), total_bookings = (total_bookings + 1), free_spaces = (free_spaces - 1) WHERE class_id = $class_id";
  mysqli_query($dbc, $increase);
  }
   mysqli_close($dbc);
```

..and the table that provides the $_POST data:

```
echo'<div class="container">';
echo'<div class="span8 offset1 well">';
echo'<p class="lead text-info">Do you want to reserve space at these classes?</p>';



//table header
echo '<table id="dancers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">';
  echo '<thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Venue</th><th>Who\'s going?</th></tr></thead>';
//create the form
echo '<form id="makebkg" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">';


//Get the class IDs from the GET to use in the POST

    foreach ($_GET['sesh'] as $class_id) {

    $sql = "SELECT class_id, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%a, %d %b') AS new_date, DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i') AS new_time, venue FROM classes WHERE class_id = '$class_id'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);


//get table data
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $date = $row["new_date"];
    $time = $row["new_time"];
    $venue = $row["venue"];
    $class_id = $row["class_id"];
  }


//Show a table of the selected classes


      echo '<tr><td>' . $date . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $time . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $venue . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $username . '</td></tr>';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="date[]" value="' . $date . '" />';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="time[]" value="' . $time . '" />';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="venue[]" value="' . $venue. '" />';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="' . $username . '" />';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="class_id[]" value="' . $class_id . '" />';



    }
 echo'</table>';



    //Go Back button
    echo '<a class="btn btn-link pull-left" href="classes.php"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Go back</a>';

  // Make booking button - LIVE
      echo'<div id="confirmbtn">';
     echo '<input type="submit" id="confirm" name="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right" value="Confirm">';
      echo '</div>';
```

Comment: What happens if you manually try an SQL query, i.e. `INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, booking_name, class_id, time_stamp) VALUES (1, "someuser", 3, NOW())`

(What is the actual error)?

Comment: the two versions work on same OS ?

Comment: P.S. it's better practice to use ticks on table names: `\`bookings`\`, not `bookings`

Comment: @khaverim totally optional unless using reserved words

Comment: Should parameterize these queries. You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: @nogad hence better practice :-)

Comment: optional is not better, its OPTIONAL

Comment: @nogad safer is better.

Comment: A common cause for problems after php updates are differences in error display settings; perhaps now warnings are displayed, your session is not started so there is no username?

Comment: `"without error"` - You're not *checking* for errors.  That doesn't mean there *aren't* any.

Comment: safer is knowing what the reserved words are in the first place.

Comment: @nogad just memorize these and you'll never need ticks: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Show the bookings table structure.And make sure the $_GET['sesh'] is what you think it is and if it also exists in the database

Comment: @khaverim no only the RESERVED words need ticks not the key words.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I finally fixed the problem.
It turns out that the hosting company had changed the MySQL mode to 'strict'.

The INSERT statement here left some table columns blank and strict mode rejects the entire insert as a result. Changing the mode right before the insert command was a quicker way to get around the problem than updating the insert command:

```
  // TURN OFF STRICT MYSQL MODE
  $strict = "SET sql_mode = ''";
  mysqli_query($dbc, $strict);
```

Thanks for all the advice and tolerance of an indolent coder.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to check your query?

```
error_reporting(1);

$q = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if (!$q)
{
  echo 'Error' . mysqli_error($dbc);
}
```

Do same for other query.

Comment: how about displaying the actual error? `mysqli_error()`

Comment: Edited, error can be showed by simple adding a error_reporting(1); on top of a script

Comment: `mysqli_error()` requires the db connection -> [`string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15426237)

Comment: @wvega Please be careful, when reviewing. This post is an answer and should not be deleted!

Comment: @Mario  I've added the error reporting code and while Error is echoed before the redirect, no error codes or details are shown.

Comment: @khaverim A direct query appears to execute without error (using the error reporting commands Mario suggested here) but still nothing is stored in the table. I'm wondering if the table is corrupted, or if I'm missing something in the error reporting code.

Comment: Try to add in script on top var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_GET); to see if u get anything in array.

Comment: Maybe to try change this `$class_id = (int)$classes;` to `$class_id = (int)$classes['class_id'];` because if u try to var_dump($classes); u will get a index of a array items.

Comment: @Mario Yeah, the array is grabbing the data fine:

_'array(6) { ["date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Mon, 27 Mar" } ["time"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "18:15" } ["venue"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "test venue" } ["username"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "test user" } ["class_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "610" } ["submit"]=> string(7) "Confirm" } array(0) { }'_

Still getting an error but no details from 'mysqli_error($query)'. All the code works fine in local test, the live table isn't crashed but the INSERT statement just will not do the job, absolutely bewildering.

Comment: If your `user_id` is set in `PRIMARY KEY` and `AUTO INCREMENT` in database remove it from query. Other thing is that u didn't closed your `foreach` loop in your first code block `isset($_POST['submit'])` just after `mysqli_query($dbc, $query);`. Adding a `}` will need to solve your problem.

Comment: @Mario - Thanks for all your help, took the web company telling me they'd switched to strict mode to figure it out but appreciate your efforts v much